# SharePoint - Microsoft Graph API: subsites list is empty

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API does not return the subsites list for the root site when calling

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites
```

(after going through the OAuth2 boilerplate).

I have checked my subsite url, it's well under

```
GET https://{org_name}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysite}
```

However, if I try to get the site by path like mentioned here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getbypath?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/mysite
```

it finds the site, and returns its info. This requires me to know the name of the site in advance. But I want to be able to list sites first, and then pick one.

My question is, what is the point of the listing endpoint `/sites/root/sites` if it returns nothing or am I missing on some setting that makes the site not listable?

I am using the scope `Sites.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the issue in Graph Explorer? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: thanks for trying I was able to find the gotcha. I posted a solution below

Answer (score 0):

It turns out authorization code was the wrong approach since it connects only on behalf of one user, while sharepoint endpoint lists sites for the whole organization. I tried another flow which is connecting on behalf of an application / organization using the admin consent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta

it is a slightly altered version of the client credentials grant, since in the standart OAuth 2 client credentials grant requires only one request, but this one needs two requests. I would say it is a mix between authorization code and client credentials. This is only specific to Microsoft. Anyway, after going through that flow, I was able to see the list of sites. Problem resolved.

Comment: You should be using the Sites.Selected Application permission. This permission allows your admin to assign application permissions to a specific site. If you use the Application permissions as described in that article, the permissions are granted to ALL sites, which is probably not what your admin wants.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I am not able to try to confirm